# Django model forms custom init returning tuple when initial given

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model form, which I'm trying to pass a model instance to initialize values:

```
class ProjectModelForm(ModelForm):

    class meta:
        model = Project

    def __init__(self, project=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjectModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if project:
            self.fields['zipcode'].initial = project.zipcode
```

The problem is that the field seems to be populated with a tuple:

```
    (u'90210',)
```

This happens even when I hardcode with a value I know to be an integer or string:

`self.fields['zipcode'].initial = 90210` renders as `(90210,)`.

`self.fields['zipcode'].initial = '90210'` renders as `('90210',)`.

Could someone explain what is happening here, and suggest the best route to rendering the result as a simple string?

Any help much appreciated.

**EDIT**

models.py:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ...
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Can you show models code?

Comment: Its not `intial` its `initial`. Maybe you have a typo there or you are doing it wrong.

Comment: oops. Yes - typo in the post, NOT in the code.

Comment: What do you mean by render? Can you show how are you outputting it?

Comment: how are you sending in the `project` object? Is it an instance of the `Project` model ?

Comment: I gotta the same problem. Did you solve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an initial dictionary of default values when initializing the form:

In View:

```
initial = {}
if project:
    initial.update({'zipcode': project.zipcode})

form = ProjectModelForm(initial=initial)
```

Comment: Actually, that's what I have at the moment, but I wanted to be a bit more pyhtonic and concise and pass in various arguments to modify the form. And I want to keep all this logic in the form class and out of views.

Comment: @DarwinTech `self.fields['zipcode'].initial = '90210'` should work though. I don't see any mistake in this line of code.

Comment: When you say `renders as ('90210',)` do you mean it displayed like this on a web page?

Comment: yes, in the form field (text input), it is displayed as `('90210',)` exactly.

Comment: Sorry the error was mine. I had a trailing comma after `project.zipcode` so the variable was treated as a tuple. :/